# Cannot connect from client side to web method on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

i'm trying to connect from html page to web method with ajax function

```
    $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:43599/WebForm1.aspx/GetWeatherResultsbyscript",
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data:{Zip:input},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data,result) {
                    alert(result.d);
                },
                error: function () { alert(" Server not found"); }
            });

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
    private object GetWeatherResultsbyscript(string Zip) {

        ServiceReference1.ForecastReturn result = new ServiceReference1.ForecastReturn();
        ServiceReference1.WeatherSoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.WeatherSoapClient();
        result = client.GetCityForecastByZIP(Zip);
        return (result);


    }
```

As a result i'm getting that server is not found, but if i delete to rows in ajax function

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",`
```

i'm getting 'undefined' as a result.

Can anyone tell what i did wrong in this implication of connection to web method?

Comment: The GetWeatherResultsbyscript method should be public.

Comment: Ain't working with public either

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

The method should be public. Try the code below,

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public object GetWeatherResultsbyscript(string Zip) {    
     ServiceReference1.ForecastReturn result = new ServiceReference1.ForecastReturn();
     ServiceReference1.WeatherSoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.WeatherSoapClient();
     result = client.GetCityForecastByZIP(Zip);
     return (result);
 }
```

Also,

The application name is missing in the URL: http://localhost:43599/application name/WebForm1.aspx

Comment: No ,it still ain't working ,with public method and json attribute, it's error

Comment: What is the error you are getting now? Are you able to  hit the GetWeatherResultsbyscript method?

Comment: No
 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED –

Comment: Looks like you are missing the application name in the URL: http://localhost:43599/<application name>/WebForm1.aspx